# Fix drywall around electrical box

Tags: drywall, repair, receptacle, kitchens, backsplash

I decided to replace my kitchen backsplash only to damage the drywall behind it.

How do I fix the drywall around electric box so that it is not flimsy and it is safe?

[image: backsplash]

Comment: Drywall gets its strength by bridging two or more studs.  Since the tile is adhered to the drywall, you probably can not remove them without damaging the drywall.  Best way to fix is probably remove more to expose studs to the left and right, replace drywall, then reapply your new backsplash.

Comment: First you need to finish the demolition then you can cut out  all the damaged drywall, clean up the ragged breaks and prep for new patch to be installed. There are many questions on DIY Home improvement stack on how to repair drywall. - https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=drywall+patch -  YouTube will also  give you some knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I would demo the entire back splash area removing all the Sheetrock.
Trying to save 10$ (about a sheet) makes no sense to me because the Sheetrock gets damaged or has residue on it. I would rip& strip the tile and Sheetrock out and then if replacing with Sheetrock use green board or if tile use backer board to replace the Sheetrock.

Replacing a large piece will look better in the long run and save a lot of time. For the cost of 1 maybe 2 sheets.

If you cut just above the tile this can help keep the strip narrow but I usually go close to the cabinets as seams up there are the easiest to hide as they are not in direct view.